# postgres query to extract data from Date\time column filtering based on month and time

Tags: python, postgresql

```
    Date/Time                   mydata1         mydata2
    -------------------  ----------------------------
    2020/09/22 00:02:00     data2              somedata2
    2020/09/22 00:04:00     data3              somedata3
    2020/09/23 00:02:00     data4              somedata4
    2020/09/23 00:04:00     data3              somedata5
    2020/09/22 00:00:00     data1              somedata1
```

`Date/Time`, `mydata1` and `mydata2` are columns.
So consider I have data from 2 months, so I would like to give a query to  extract for 1 month for a specific time range. NOTE:Date/time is a text field

Here the with query I should extract the data for the month September between time 02:00 and 04:00 so the output should be like:

```
2020/09/22 00:02:00      data2         somedata2
2020/09/22 00:04:00      data3         somedata3
2020/09/23 00:02:00      data4         somedata4
2020/09/23 00:04:00      data3         somedata5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beginning solution would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE dt_fld between '2020/09/01'::date AND '2020/09/30'::date
```

This for the month of September. `dt_fld` is a made up name to stand in for whatever your `Date/Time` field is actually called. `::date` is Postgres shorthand for `CAST` of text to `date` type. Another way of saying `CAST('2020/09/01' as date)`.

**UPDATE**

The desired solution:

```
CREATE TABLE month_test("Date/Time" varchar, mydata1 varchar, mydata2 varchar);

insert into month_test values ('2020/09/22 00:02:00', 'data2', 'somedata2');
insert into month_test values ('2020/09/22 00:04:00', 'data3', 'somedata3');
insert into month_test values ('2020/09/23 00:02:00', 'data4', 'somedata4');
insert into month_test values ('2020/09/23 00:04:00', 'data3', 'somedata5');
insert into month_test values ('2020/09/22 00:00:00', 'data1', 'somedata1');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    month_test
WHERE
    date_part('month', "Date/Time"::timestamp) = 9
    AND "Date/Time"::time BETWEEN '00:02:00'::time
    AND '00:04:00'::time;

 Date/Time      | mydata1 |  mydata2  
---------------------+---------+-----------
 2020/09/22 00:02:00 | data2   | somedata2
 2020/09/22 00:04:00 | data3   | somedata3
 2020/09/23 00:02:00 | data4   | somedata4
 2020/09/23 00:04:00 | data3   | somedata5
```

Uses `date_part` to find only those timestamps that are in month of September. Then only those that are in the time range `00:02:00 - 00:04:00`

Comment: thanks for the reply .what is dt_fld and '2020/09/01'::date' date in this stands for.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: SELECT * FROM usage_stats WHERE Date/Time between '2020/09/01'::date AND '2020/09/30'::date;  i am getting the following error:ERROR:  column "date" does not exist , column Date/Time is present

Comment: I would strongly discourage using a field name like `Date/Time`. In order for that to work you had to quote it ("Date/Time") on table creation. That means you will have to quote every time you use it afterwards, `WHERE "Date/Time"`. You get the error because the parse gets to the `/` and considers `Date` the field name and then because it is not quoted folds it to lower case `date`, which is not found. I would spend some time here [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: the issue is here i am directly parsing the data from csv using pandas and dumping data to database so the column name is same as that of csv's.

Comment: i tried giving "Date/Time" the follwing error occured: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= date
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM usage_stats WHERE "Date/Time" between '20...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 50

Comment: Then you will have to quote the field name "Date/time".

Comment: any idea about the above error i have mentioned?

Comment: So "Date/Time" is not a timestamp(datetime) field, but a text field. Please add that information to your question. So do `WHERE "Date/Time"::date`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine,  i have one more requirement like filtering it based on time for ex : from 00:00:00 to 00:02:00 it is also already available in Date/time column . could the filtering be added to current query, thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, change the cast from `::date` to `::timestamp` or `::timestamptz` where the latter is time zone aware. Then add the time component: `'2020/09/01 00:02:00'`.  I would add   two things to make this easier long term 1) Change the "Date/Time" field to `timestamptz`. 2) Read these: [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html) and [Date.Time Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: SELECT * FROM usage_stats WHERE "Date/Time"::timestamp between '2020/09/01 00:02:00'::timestamp AND '2020/09/30 00:04:00'::timestamp; here i am getting the output for month but no filtration is happening based on time.

Comment: Actually what is happening like i am searching for one month data and i am getting filtered data which actually has one day of a month (since only that day data is available for the current month), so if i am trying to filter with the day and specific time it is happening, but i need to search for a month and under that time filtering should be there.(it is not happening), so what i need exactly is 1 months 2 hour data for each data from 00:02:00 - 04:00:00

Comment: You are going to need to provide some sample data and expected output in your question to get an answer.

Comment: I have updated the question , sorry for the wrong presentation ,thanks in advance

Comment: See UPDATE to answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine , like if i need to search for muliplte months like sept and oct between the time 2:00 and 4:00, is there a possible way for this.

Comment: Yes, but that was not your original question.  You have the query and it can be modified for multiple months. I will leave that to you. Hint: use `IN`.

Comment: Thanks , i was able to do the filtration.